# VB.NET LINQ to DataSet (SQL 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' alternative)

Tags: vb.net, linq, dataset

I would like to join two DataTables and create the third one from the result. The result DataTable should have three columns:

- ID
- Name
- YearOfBirth

My Compile options:

- Option explicit: On
- Option strict: On
- Option compare: Binary
- Option infer: Off

  ```
  Dim dr As DataRow

  REM Dt1
  Dim Dt1 As New DataTable
  Dt1.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
  Dt1.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))

  dr = Dt1.NewRow
  dr("ID") = 1
  dr("Name") = "Peter"
  Dt1.Rows.Add(dr)

  dr = Dt1.NewRow
  dr("ID") = 2
  dr("Name") = "Anna"
  Dt1.Rows.Add(dr)

  dr = Dt1.NewRow
  dr("ID") = 3
  dr("Name") = "John"
  Dt1.Rows.Add(dr)
  REM End Dt1

  REM Dt2
  Dim Dt2 As New DataTable
  Dt2.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
  Dt2.Columns.Add("YearOfBirth", GetType(Integer))

  dr = Dt2.NewRow
  dr("ID") = 1
  dr("YearOfBirth") = 1970
  Dt2.Rows.Add(dr)

  dr = Dt2.NewRow
  dr("ID") = 2
  dr("YearOfBirth") = 1980
  Dt2.Rows.Add(dr)
  REM End Dt2

  Dim Dt3 As New DataTable

  Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = From dr1 In Dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                         Group Join dr2 In Dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                         On dr1.Field(Of Integer)("ID") Equals dr2.Field(Of Integer)("ID")
                                         Into joined = Group
                                         From j In joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         Select New With
                                             {
                                             .ID = dr1.Field(Of Integer)("ID"),
                                             .Name = dr1.Field(Of String)("Name"),
                                             .YearOfBirth = j.Field(Of Integer)("YearOfBirth")
                                             }


  Dt3 = query.CopyToDataTable
  ```

But I get the error message in editor (VS 2017):

"Error  BC36754:
'IEnumerable(Of anonymous type: ID As Integer, Name As String, YearOfBirth As Integer)' cannot be converted to 'IEnumerable(Of DataRow)' because 'anonymous type: ID As Integer, Name As String, YearOfBirth As Integer' is not derived from 'DataRow', as required for the 'Out' generic parameter 'T' in 'Interface IEnumerable(Of Out T)'."

Comment: You can't call `CopyToDataTable` unless your list contains `DataRows` which yours doesn't. You need to create the `DataTable` yourself and then loop through the results of your query, adding a `DataRow` for each item.

Comment: Thank you, but I have some mistake in the query.

Comment: If somebody could write correct part of code (Dim query...) for me, it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select New` without specifying class name as query result will return anonymous type (such like `IEnumerable(Of AnonymousType)`), and [`CopyToDataTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) throwing exception because `IEnumerable(Of AnonymousType)` cannot be converted directly to `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`.

Hence, you need to convert anonymous type into `DataRow` using additional `Select` method that iterates `IEnumerable(Of AnonymousType)` contents and returns `DataRow` with [`DataTable.NewRow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) (using prepared `DataTable` which includes column names as result set):

```
' joined DataTable columns
Dim JoinedDT As New DataTable
JoinedDT.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
JoinedDT.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
JoinedDT.Columns.Add("YearOfBirth", GetType(Integer))

' other stuff

Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = (From dr1 In Dt1.AsEnumerable() _
                                       Group Join dr2 In Dt2.AsEnumerable() _
                                       On dr1.Field(Of Integer)("ID") Equals dr2.Field(Of Integer)("ID") _
                                       Into joined = Group _
                                       From j In joined.DefaultIfEmpty() _
                                       Select New With
                                       {
                                           .ID = dr1.Field(Of Integer)("ID"),
                                           .Name = dr1.Field(Of String)("Name"),
                                           .YearOfBirth = If(j IsNot Nothing, j.Field(Of Integer)("YearOfBirth"), 0)
                                       }).Select(Function(r)
                                           ' use `DataTable.NewRow` here
                                           Dim row As DataRow = JoinedDT.NewRow()
                                           row("ID") = r.ID
                                           row("Name") = r.Name
                                           row("YearOfBirth") = r.YearOfBirth
                                           Return row
                                       End Function)

Dt3 = query.CopyToDataTable()
```

Reference:

[Get linq to return IEnumerable<DataRow> result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503517/get-linq-to-return-ienumerabledatarow-result) (C# version)

Comment: Your code is OK, but only under condition, that both DataTables Dt1 and Dt2 have 3 rows with ID 1,2 and 3. If the DataTable Dt2 has only two rows with ID 1 and 2 (without ID 3), I get the error: "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: row'".

Comment: I just found that `YearOfBirth` only contains 2 rows (for ID 3 it's set to `Nothing`). Use [`If` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) with 2 arguments to check against `Nothing` and return default integer value if `DataRow` has `Nothing` value in it.

Comment: If I use `row("YearOfBirth") = If(r.YearOfBirth, 0)`, the query is not correct. I see this error in Error List: Error BC33107: First operand in a binary 'If' expression must be nullable or a reference type. If I use in the part of code `.YearOfBirth = j.Field(Of Integer)("YearOfBirth")` `Object`, instead of `Integer`, the query is formally OK, but I get the error after launch: "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: row". If I use `Try...Catch`, I see that the error is on the line `Select New With`.

Comment: Well, I had put check against `Nothing` in wrong place. It should be placed in `Select New With` as you're said, also confirmed by [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201168/left-outer-join-linq-to-datatable). Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: The query is excellent now. You helped me a lot. Many thanks.